# ubuntu 17 - docker ce - unmet dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to make my very first ubuntu installations to form the basis of my docker hosting system.

I make an installation of ubunto from ubuntu-17.04-server-amd64.iso and try to accept all default choices.

I then follow instructions here
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/
but when I get to 
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
I get
'unmet dependencies'.

I'm blank! What can I do?!

[image]

Comment: Ugh! Please paste text as text, then mark the lines and press the "format as code"  `{}` button on a toolbar.

Comment: I'd love to, but copy-paste from a linux machine to windows host does not seem to work. Nextissue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 17.04 is end of life and Docker CE is no longer supported on this platform. Update to 17.10 or use an LTS release.

[The current Ubuntu releases supported by Docker CE](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) can be found on Docker's web site.

> To install Docker CE, you need the 64-bit version of one of these Ubuntu versions:
>
> - Artful 17.10 (Docker CE 17.11 Edge and higher only)
> - Xenial 16.04 (LTS)
> - Trusty 14.04 (LTS)